# How to deploy to Azure Static Web App with database connection in Svelte using GitHub workflow?

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-cosmosdb, svelte, azure-static-web-app

I have created a Svelte skeleton web application and a Cosmos NoSQL database. I installed the `swa` CLI tool using `npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli` command. Furthermore, I was following the [Azure Cosmos DB Tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/database-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=bash) under the Database connection section in the Azure Static Web Apps (SWA) Documentation.

I created the sample data successfully on Azure CosmosDB according to the documentation. Then, I added the `list` API to test the deployment. This is the content of the `src/routes/+page.svelte` home page:

```
<script>
  async function list() {
    const query = `
      {
        people {
          items {
            id
            Name
          }
        }
      }`;

    const endpoint = '/data-api/graphql';
    const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: query })
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    console.table(result.data.people.items);
  }
</script>

<h1>Static Web Apps with Database Connections</h1>
<blockquote>Open the console in the browser developer tools to see the API responses.</blockquote>
<div>
  <button id="list" on:click={list}>List</button>
</div>
```

## Configuration setup

I set the database connection string environment variable:

```bash
export DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING='<YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING>'
```

I initialized the SWA configuration with the `swa init` command and the configuration files under the `/swa-db-connections` folder are the following:

- staticwebapp.database.config.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/releases/download/v0.9.7/dab.draft.schema.json",
  "data-source": {
    "database-type": "cosmosdb_nosql",
    "connection-string": "@env('DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING')",
    "options": {
      "database": "MyTestPersonDatabase",
      "schema": "staticwebapp.database.schema.gql"
    }
  },
  "runtime": {
    "graphql": {
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "/graphql",
      "allow-introspection": true
    },
    "host": {
      "cors": {
        "origins": ["http://localhost:4280"],
        "allow-credentials": false
      },
      "authentication": {
        "provider": "StaticWebApps"
      },
      "mode": "production"
    }
  },
  "entities": {
    "Person": {
      "source": "MyTestPersonContainer",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "actions": ["*"],
          "role": "anonymous"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- staticwebapp.database.schema.gql:

```
type Person @model {
  id: ID
  Name: String
}
```

This is the content of the `/svelte.config.js` file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';

export default {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter()
  }
};
```

## Page not Found Error

When I would like to emulate the Static Web App on the `/src` folder with the `swa start ./src --data-api-location swa-db-connections` command, I got the following output:

```
[dataApi] Information: Microsoft.DataApiBuilder 0.9.7+e560142426d1c080b9fd7b7fabff51a276f6bf61
[dataApi] Information: User provided config file: staticwebapp.database.config.json
[dataApi] Loading config file from staticwebapp.database.config.json.
[dataApi] Information: Loaded config file: staticwebapp.database.config.json
[dataApi] Information: Setting default minimum LogLevel: Error for Production mode.
[dataApi] Starting the runtime engine...
[swa] 
[swa] Using workflow file:
[swa]   C:\Users\z0190983\ws\personal\pomodoro-svelte\.github\workflows\azure-static-web-apps.yml
[swa] 
[swa] Serving static content:
[swa]   C:\Users\z0190983\ws\personal\pomodoro-svelte\src
[swa]
[swa] Azure Static Web Apps emulator started at http://localhost:4280. Press CTRL+C to exit.
[swa]
[swa]
[dataApi] Redirecting to https is disabled.
[dataApi] Loading config file from staticwebapp.database.config.json.
[dataApi] info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[63]
[dataApi]       User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\z0190983\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
[dataApi] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
[dataApi]       Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
[dataApi] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
[dataApi]       Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
[dataApi] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
[dataApi]       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[dataApi] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
[dataApi]       Hosting environment: Production
[dataApi] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
[dataApi]       Content root path: C:\Users\z0190983\ws\personal\pomodoro-svelte\swa-db-connections
[swa] GET http://localhost:4280/404.html - 404
```

Somehow the Svelte web application could not be found and a `404: Not Found` page was displayed:

[image]

Questions:

- How to emulate the Svelte application using the `swa` CLI tool locally?
- What is the minimal GitHub workflow file to deploy the web application automatically?

Comment: It's ok to post a question, and answer your own question. But... there's no specific question here; rather, it's a premise, followed by an open-ended question )(that you then answer). And the answer is more of a blog-style answer, not something specific.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have updated the question with the error message that I encountered during the implementation. I hope it is more specific and less open-ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Emulating Static Web App locally

First, install the [static site generator adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static) in SvelteKit. Install it via `npm install -D @sveltejs/adapter-static` and then configure the `svelte.config.js` file for the production build:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

export default {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      fallback: 'index.html'
    })
  }
};
```

The fallback name is important because the entry has to be either `index.html` or `Index.html` page. After that, you have to create a build using this command:

```bash
npm run build
```

Notice that, it creates a `build` folder which can be used to emulate the Static Web App locally with the `swa` CLI tool:

```bash
swa start ./build --data-api-location swa-db-connections
```

Go to the http://localhost:4280 URL, open the browser console with <kbd>F12</kbd>, and click on the List button. In the console, you'll see the items in the database container.

## The minimal Deployment file

The steps to create a GitHub workflow. Here is a minimal `azure-static-web-apps.yml` file that uses the [Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-deploy?tab=readme-ov-file) action:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches: 'main'

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Build And Deploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_BRAVE_COAST_063A3A503 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: 'upload'
          app_location: '/'
          output_location: 'build'
```

Replace the `AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_BRAVE_COAST_063A3A5033` API token secret with yours by navigating to your GitHub repository and **Settings** > **Secrets and variables** > **Actions** section. Lastly, check if the CosmosDB is connected to the Static Web App in the Azure portal:

[image]

If everything is working, you can visit and try out the web application by navigating to **Overview** > **View your application** > **Visit your site** button under the Static Web App resource.

Comment: As mentioned under the question: you should be answering something *specific*; this is more of a blog-post, as it doesn't answer something specific - it's covering a general topic you're interested in (which is fine but doesn't really fit here like this)

Comment: Also, just be careful about promotion of your own work - be crystal-clear that it's your repo you're pointing to.

Comment: @DavidMakogon The answer was adapted according to the updated question. I also referenced my repository in the answer for the complete picture.